# Was "Licence to Kill" originally titled "Licence Revoked"?

Tags: james-bond, title, licence-to-kill

Is there any proof that the James Bond movie [Licence to Kill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_to_Kill) was actually going to be titled "Licence Revoked"?

If yes, then was it because it was believed that the audience, at that time, was too stupid and would have wondered why James Bond would not be allowed to drive?

Comment: I don't think it's stupidity as much as the prevalence of a common idiom. Having one's "license revoked" in the U.S. typically refers to having one's **driver's** license taken away; so much so that any other meaning would require explanation.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with with the audience being "too stupid".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is true. When the movie was test screened in US, it had the name "Licence Revoked" but after the test screening the audience associated it too strongly with driving.

Sources: [here](http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Licence_to_Kill) and
[here](http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/2008/aug/21/1).

Some have speculated that the change might have had something to do with Greg Beeman's [License to Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_to_Drive), but this was released over a year earlier, so it's highly unlikely.